# update datasource used for Amazon machine learning ML model

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, machine-learning, boto3

I am using an amazon machine learning for creating ML models for my applications. I have created a datasource and also ML model corresponding to that datasource, however in my application new data always keeps getting added so I have to update the data file in s3 which in turn used by the datasource. So the question is how can I update the datasource corresponding to that data file without changing the datasource id and also how to update the ML model corresponding to that datasource without changing the ML model id?

I know that there are methods in Boto3 to update datasource or ML model however as far as I know it only updates the name of those objects.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that. Amazon ML datasources are immutable, save for the human-readable name attribute. Instead, when you have new data, create a new datasource that points at the same data file(s) in S3, and then train a new ML model using that datasource.

Comment: thanks for the response and yeah ultimately thats what i will have to do i guess